# get specific value from object - Typescript

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

In react application I have json response object that looks like this :

```
{
   100: "apple,
   200: "bananas",
   300: "pineapples"
 }
```

I want to get a specific value, for example, a value that corresponds to 200 - "bananas".

What is the easiest way to do this? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
const yourObject = {
   100: "apple",
   200: "bananas",
   300: "pineapples"
 }

console.log(yourObject[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON object is saved in `myJson`

```
const myJson = {
   100: "apple",
   200: "bananas",
   300: "pineapples"
 }
```

You would access `bananas` like that:

```
myJson[200]
```

Comment: can I ask you here another question related to this topic?

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question and I will try to answer that